# Só consigo ler arquivo XML no localhost

Tags: php, xml

Olá, não estou conseguido de forma alguma ler um determinado arquivo `XML` quando o meu script esta hospedado no meu servidor. O arquivo `XML` não é meu, ele é disponibilizado para a leitura, e só consigo ler com `PHP` quando testo no `localhost`. Segue meu código, me ajudem por favor!

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://stm10.igrsistemas.com.br:10522/stats?sid=1");
echo utf8_decode($xml->SONGTITLE);
```

Outro `XML` como por exemplo: http://xcast.com.br/api/VFZSQk1VMXFTVDA9KzU= e consigo ler normalmente tanto no `localhost`, quanto no meu servidor...

Comment: O que mostra o `echo`?

Comment: Mostra a informação contida na tag `SONGTITLE` vinda do arquivo XML